# When I set my background color but at the same time I can't see my drop-down list

Tags: html, css

**Run the code and add a background color you will find what problem facing I am.**
when I add my background color with overflow hidden then I can't see my dropdown list from the menu. I trying as much as but don't solve this problem from two days. what should I do now?
Please, someone, help me to solve this problem.

## Thanks

```css
.wrapper{
 width:980px;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0px;
}
.mainmenu{}
.mainmenu ul{
 list-style-type:none;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}
.mainmenu ul li{
 position:relative;
    float: left;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}
.mainmenu ul a{
 display:block;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
 margin:0px;
 padding:10px 25px;
 line-height:15px;
 text-align:middle;
 font-weight:400;
 font-size:16px;
}
.mainmenu ul li a:hover{
 background-color:#9988ff;
 color:white;
}
.mainmenu ul ul{
 position:absolute;
 display:none;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 top:35px;
 background-color:yellow;
 z-index:1;
}
.mainmenu ul ul ul{
 top:0;
 left:100%;
}
.mainmenu ul ul li{
 float:none;
 width:200px;
}
.mainmenu ul li:hover > ul{
 display:block;
}
.content{
 margin:15px;
 padding:5px;
}
.main-content{
 width:500px;
 float:left;
}
img{
 width:100%;
}
.sidebar{
 width:425px;
 float:right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hassan Softwear Inc. Consultancy</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css_five.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header"></div>
            <div class="mainmenu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Chairman</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Director</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Manager</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
                    <li><a href="#">ADMISSION</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Apply for Ai</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a>
          <ul>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a>
            <ul>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
            </ul>           
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
          </ul>         
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
        </ul>       
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Apply for Ps</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a>
          <ul>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a>
            <ul>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
            </ul>           
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
          </ul>          
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
        </ul>       
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Apply for html</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a>
          <ul>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a>
            <ul>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
            </ul>           
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
          </ul>          
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
        </ul>       
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Apply for css</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a>
          <ul>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
          </ul>          
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
        </ul>       
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Apply for Java</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Apply for Python</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Apply for Others</a></li>
      </ul>     
     </li>
                    <li><a href="#">TUTORIAL</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">JAVA</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">PYTHON</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">C++</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
                    <li><a href="#">OUR PLAN</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Diamond</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a>
          <ul>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
          </ul>          
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Platinum</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
        </ul>       
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Golden</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
        </ul>       
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Silver</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
        </ul>       
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Bronze</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
        </ul>       
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Aluminium</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
        </ul>       
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Sodium</a></li>
      </ul>     
     </li>
                    <li><a href="#">NOTICE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="content"></div>
            <div class="footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please describe in more detail what you're trying to do, and what's going wrong?

Comment: someone solved the problem thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not set overflow hidden, it will hide the drop down menu.

You will find that it is not working if only set the background color for div.mainmenu, because it cannot get the height of child. Hence it is showing as 0px height and no background color can be seen.

To let the parent get the height, you can simply set height:35px , or add a div with style="clear:both" after the ul.

Following code is using a clear both div.

```css
.wrapper{
 width:980px;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0px;
}
.mainmenu{background-color:red;}
.mainmenu ul{
 list-style-type:none;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}
.mainmenu ul li{
 position:relative;
    float: left;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}
.mainmenu ul a{
 display:block;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
 margin:0px;
 padding:10px 25px;
 line-height:15px;
 text-align:middle;
 font-weight:400;
 font-size:16px;
}
.mainmenu ul li a:hover{
 background-color:#9988ff;
 color:white;
}
.mainmenu ul ul{
 position:absolute;
 display:none;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 top:35px;
 background-color:yellow;
 z-index:1;
}
.mainmenu ul ul ul{
 top:0;
 left:100%;
}
.mainmenu ul ul li{
 float:none;
 width:200px;
}
.mainmenu ul li:hover > ul{
 display:block;
}
.content{
 margin:15px;
 padding:5px;
}
.main-content{
 width:500px;
 float:left;
}
img{
 width:100%;
}
.sidebar{
 width:425px;
 float:right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hassan Softwear Inc. Consultancy</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css_five.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header"></div>
            <div class="mainmenu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Chairman</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Director</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Manager</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
                    <li><a href="#">ADMISSION</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Apply for Ai</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a>
          <ul>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a>
            <ul>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
            </ul>           
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
          </ul>         
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
        </ul>       
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Apply for Ps</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a>
          <ul>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a>
            <ul>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
            </ul>           
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
          </ul>          
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
        </ul>       
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Apply for html</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a>
          <ul>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a>
            <ul>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
            </ul>           
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
          </ul>          
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
        </ul>       
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Apply for css</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a>
          <ul>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
          </ul>          
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
        </ul>       
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Apply for Java</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Apply for Python</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Apply for Others</a></li>
      </ul>     
     </li>
                    <li><a href="#">TUTORIAL</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">JAVA</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">PYTHON</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">C++</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
                    <li><a href="#">OUR PLAN</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Diamond</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a>
          <ul>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
          </ul>          
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Platinum</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
        </ul>       
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Golden</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
        </ul>       
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Silver</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
        </ul>       
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Bronze</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
        </ul>       
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Aluminium</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY A</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY B</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY C</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY D</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CATEGORY E</a></li>
        </ul>       
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Sodium</a></li>
      </ul>     
     </li>
                    <li><a href="#">NOTICE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul><div style="clear:both"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="content"></div>
            <div class="footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```